# Handling very large datasets in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a relatively large dataset (> 15 GB) stored in a single file as a Pandas dataframe. I would like to convert this data to TFRecords format and feed this into my computational graph later on. I was following this tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py.

However, this still involves loading the entirety of the dataset into memory. Is there a method that allows you to convert large datasets into TFrecords directly without loading everything into memory? Are TFRecords even needed in this context or can I just read the arrays from disk during training?

Alternatives are using `np.memmap` or breaking the dataframe apart into smaller parts, but I was wondering if it was possible to convert the entire dataset into TFrecord format.

Comment: If this might be of use to anyone - right now my experimental data arrives in managable chunks, which I store in HDF5 format. To convert this to a single TFrecords dataset, I convert these files to a single Parquet file, conduct the necessary preprocessing in Spark, then convert the preprocessed data to TFrecords format using https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/tree/master/spark/spark-tensorflow-connector - in practice I find this to be much slower on GPU than having the entire dataset loaded into memory, perhaps this is being bottlenecked by the time taken to load the data from disk...

Comment: From my experience the np.memmap function was the best choice for handling large dstasets. So I would either split your file into several smaller batch sets ou load with memmap. I don't reallysee any advantage in using a TFrecord for it.

Comment: You might be able to use [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) to load in your dataframe piece by piece and convert it to a TFRecords file.

Comment: This isn't really a tf question, it's a pandas question. Once you can partially load chunks of the df from disk, you have all that you need to then write out a series of TFRecords. So the first datapoint is to understand, in what format is your df serialized to disk?